# Cannot find React module when adding local npm dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My local custom module inside `node_modules` does not have access to the `react` package that it's parent has.

I have the following code:

```
// SomeComponent.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  View
} from 'react-native'
import CustomComponent from 'react-native-my-super-components'

export default SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CustomComponent />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I have a directory that has been `npm link`ed and is called `react-native-my-super-components`.

```
// index.js of 'react-native-my-super-components'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native'

export default SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>SomeComponent</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I have called `npm link react-native-my-super-component` in my project containing `SomeComponent.js`.

It's `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-my-super-component",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Super Component",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Naoto Ida",
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=15.3.2",
    "react-native": ">=0.35.0"
  }
}
```

I don't see any differences compared to other `node_modules`. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resolving `react` from `react-native-my-super-component`, node will search in node_modules from `react-native-my-super-component` folder or from `react-native-my-super-component` parents.

You cannot have the module resolving system working the same way when using `npm link`.

So you can:

- install the required missing dependency as 'dev dependency' in `react-native-my-super-component` folder
- for React, that must be a singleton, you must create an alias in your webpack config file to resolve 'react' from every linked module the same way.

for example in you webpack config file, add in dev mode:

```
    {
        resolve: {
            alias: [
                'react': path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/react')
            ]
        }
    }
```

This solution requires module 'path' to create an absolute path to your react module: ( `import path from 'path';` ) but in you can at first try a static path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I can push my `react-native-my-super-component` to a remote repo, should I just do that and `npm install`? I've used webpack before to transpile from ES6 to old JS, but no so much with this kind of project.

Comment: yes. Use `npm link` to be able to have your main project working with  `react-native-my-super-component` when it has is own dev process running. Then in prod, or when `react-native-my-super-component` is pushed on a remote repo, just use `npm install react-native-my-super-component`.